# Java's BlockingQueue design question

Tags: java, blockingqueue

the method java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue.add(E e)'s JavaDoc reads:

> boolean add(E e)
>
> Inserts the specified element into
>   this queue if it is possible to do so
>   immediately without violating capacity
>   restrictions, returning true upon
>   success and throwing an
>   IllegalStateException if no space is
>   currently available. When using a
>   capacity-restricted queue, it is
>   generally preferable to use offer.

My question is: will it ever return false? if not, why does this method return a boolean?
It seems weird to me. What is the design decision behind this?

Thanks for your knowledge!
Manuel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It follows the contract of [`Collection.add(E e)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) (since `BlockingQueue` is a subtype of `Collection`):

> If a collection refuses to add a
>   particular element for any reason
>   other than that it already contains
>   the element, it must throw an
>   exception (rather than returning
>   false). This preserves the invariant
>   that a collection always contains the
>   specified element after this call
>   returns.

Comment: Essentially, only `Set` types return false for `add`.

Answer (score 2):

The decision behind is: fail fast. The IllegalStateException will be thrown, if the queue has a limited capacity. IllegalStateException is a RuntimeException. So if the exception gets thrown, you probably have a fault in your application logic or your application logic is not defensive enough. Or to say it in other words: If you like to use a limited queue, your application should deal with it properly (use `offer` instead).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it has a boolean return type because it's a subinterface of `Queue`, which also has a `boolean add(E obj)` method (which in turn is derived from `Collection`). Certain `Queue` implementations reject attempts to add objects to the queue by returning false.

**Thus, the answer to your question is that implementations of BlockingQueue will never return false.**

Answer (score 1):

The method returns a boolean because it overrides [`Collection#add(E e)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29).